# Preencher inputs conforme seleção do option

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Olá!

Tenho esta View onde eu atualizo o valor e a quantidade de um produto no Banco de Dados selecionando ele na ViewBag, funciona perfeitamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu populo essa ViewBag da seguinte forma no Controller:

```
ViewData["ProductId"] = new SelectList(_context.Product, "Id", "ProductName");
```

A tabela Product tem Id, ProductName, ProductQuantity e ProductPrice.

Meu problema é:

Eu quero colocar mais dois inputs(ou algo semelhante) nessa tela, que mostrem a quantidade(ProductQuantity) e preço(ProductPrice) atual conforme o produto selecionado, mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Código da view (com os inputs que quero preencher) está aqui:

```html
<form asp-action="AddRemoveProduct">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProductId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select id="idProduto" asp-for="ProductId" class="idProduto form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ProductId"></select>
                <input class="control-label"type="text" placeholder="Quantidade atual aqui" />
                <input class="control-label" type="text"placeholder="Preço atual aqui"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="ProductId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Quantity" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Quandidade a Adicionar ou Remover" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" placeholder="Alterar Valor do Produdo" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso? seria com Javascript, com algum recurso do Razor... Já pesquisei de todas as formas e não encontrei nada que resolvesse meu problema.

Por favor, antes de votar negativo, me diga o que estou errando na pergunta ou o que eu poderia fazer. Estou iniciando como programador e estou quebrando a cabeça faz dias nisso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

Criei uma função com Javascript para armazenar em uma variável o *value* do *select* onde mostra o nome do produto e atribui esse *value* a dois id:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#idProduto").change(function () {
                var select = document.getElementById('idProduto');
                document.getElementById('productPrice').value = select.value;
                document.getElementById('productQuantity').value = select.value;
            });
        });
```

Criei mais duas *ViewData* no *Controller* recebendo o Id, mas uma mostrando o valor e outra a quantidade, desta forma:

```
ViewData["ProductName"] = new SelectList(_context.Product, "Id", "ProductName");
ViewData["ProductQuantity"] = new SelectList(_context.Product, "Id", "ProductQuantity");
ViewData["ProductPrice"] = new SelectList(_context.Product, "Id", "ProductPrice");
```

Depois disso, criei mais dois *selects*, que recebem o *value* do primeiro *select*, pela função Javascript:

**O html ficou desta forma:**

```html
<form asp-action="AddRemoveProduct">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProductId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select id="idProduto" asp-for="ProductId" class="idProduto form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ProductName"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="ProductId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>      
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <label >Quantidade Atual</label>
                        <select disabled id="productQuantity" asp-for="ProductId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ProductQuantity"></select>                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <label>Preço Atual</label>
                        <select disabled id="productPrice" asp-for="ProductId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ProductPrice"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>               
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Quantidade Adicionar/Remover</label>
                <input asp-for="Quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Informe a quantidade" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Novo Preço</label>
                <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" placeholder="Informe o novo valor do produdo" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts {

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#idProduto").change(function () {
                var select = document.getElementById('idProduto');
                document.getElementById('productPrice').value = select.value;
                document.getElementById('productQuantity').value = select.value;
            });
        });
    </script>
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

**A tela ficou desta forma:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei se existe uma forma mais fácil ou mais correta, mas nesse caso resolveu meu problema, espero que ajude mais alguém.